# Sampling areas based on water mask using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, feature-collection

I am trying to sample a large image and I only want to keep points that fall within a water mask.

I can successfully sample small numbers of points by using a mask, but the algorithm chokes at larger numbers of pixels. This is surprising because I specify the `numPixels` argument as a large number, but the resultant `featurecollection` only consists of a small number of points.

Here is my `.sample()` call with the masking operation:

```
var water_mask = ee.Image("JRC/GSW1_3/GlobalSurfaceWater")
                    .select(['max_extent'],['is_water'])

var montana = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2018/States")
                   .filter(ee.Filter.eq("NAME","Montana"))

var my_img = img1.addBands(img2).mask(water_mask)


// Call to .sample()
var samples = my_img.sample({'region':montana,
                          'projection':"EPSG:4326",
                          'scale':30,
                          'numPixels':500})
print(samples.size())
// Even though numPixels is specified as 500, the size of 'samples' is only 7
```

This behavior is synonymous to sampling an unmasked image and filtering the resultant `featurecollection` by the mask.

For example,

```
// First add the water_mask bands to the image, so that they can be sampled
var synonymous = my_img.addBands(water_mask)
                 .addBands(ndvi)

                 // Sample masked image - note numPixels
                 .sample({'region':montana,
                          'projection':"EPSG:4326",
                          'scale':30,
                          'numPixels':500})
                          
                 // Filter feature collection by condition
                 .filter(ee.Filter.eq('is_water',1))

print(synonymous.size())
// This results in only 7 points as well
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this operation?

Here is a link to my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/195b11ed5981b695bfe9bbe2da41acac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for `sample()` explicitly state:

> Note that the default behavior is to drop features that intersect
> masked pixels, which result in null-valued properties.

Even though you've only got 1 class, what you're trying to do is a stratified sampling, so use `stratifiedSample`.

```
var samples = lst.addBands(water_mask)
                .addBands(ndvi)
                .updateMask(water_mask)
                .stratifiedSample({
                  numPoints: 500,
                  classBand: 'is_water',
                  region: montana,
                  projection: "EPSG:4326",
                  scale :30
                })
```

Note that Montana at 30m is pretty big (422 million pixels), so you might have to do this with an export.

Also, don't clip; you're already using the geometry for a region, so clipping the images wastes time/memory.

Comment: Does this approach have vastly different memory constraints than `.sample()`? I am unable to sample even 1 point from this image / area combination due to time out, and I would prefer not to use a conventional export because I have been using the python API to get around timeout errors.

Comment: Not memory.  But the only way to get exactly X points is to compute all the pixels to figure out which ones aren't masked in the final result, then sample the final result.  Otherwise, if you select X then compute the values for them (as sample() does), then some might end up being masked and you get less than N.  
The other option is to generate a lot more than N random points and hope that at least of them aren't masked.  Potentially faster, but you won't know how big to make N, in order to get X.